# Dynamically setting multiSelect for combobox in extJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs5, sencha-architect

I am kinda facing an interesting problem with my combobox's multiSelect property.

I have a grid with three columns ID, Name, Associated Part.

I have enabled Rowediting plugin and editors for ID is textfield(EditID), Name is textfield(EditName) and Associated Part is combobox(EditPartCombo with multiSelect true).

I have two buttons Add and Update.

When I select any row in the grid and press Update, rowediting starts at that exact position. In the Update button code, i am setting the multiselect property of EditPartCombo to false but somehow it is not reflecting.

Code on Update button:

```
{
text: 'Update Press',

handler: function(btn){

var grid = btn.up('grid');
var selection = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();


if(selection.length > 0){

combo = Ext.getCmp('EditPartCombo');
combo.multiSelect = false;
delete combo.picker;
combo.createPicker();
combo.reset();

var rowEditing = grid.getPlugin('RowEditPlugin');
var rowno = grid.store.indexOf(selection[0]);
rowEditing.cancelEdit();

rowEditing.startEdit(rowno, 1);  
}

else{ Ext.Msg.alert('Error' , 'Please Select a row to Update'); } 

}
```

In firebug when I inspect combo - it shows that multiSelect as false but still i am able to select multiple values.

Not sure what am I doing wrong?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a question.. Then whats the point of Multiselect? Why do you even have it?

Comment: Actually I just added Add button too. So if Add is pressed, I need it multiselect. If Update is pressed, I need it as SingleSelect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cange a config value after a component is created, it is not guaranteed that this value is applied. For some config option, it is and for other it doesn't work.

I would recommend you to `Ext.create` the combobox, and inject this multiSelect configuration at that time. Like this for one button you create it with `multiSelect` enabled, and disabled for the other.